# Magento 2 : Admin page pages redirect to Admin my account

Tags: magento-2.1, admin-panel, redirection

After login My magento 2 admin all pages are redirect to admin my account page i dont now what happen. its work yesterday good. issue start today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its sometimes because its time to change your password. Change `password` of ADMIN login and try again. It will work.

Comment: Yes its working can you tell me what is actual problem?

Comment: Password is expired after specific time and thats reason it redirect admin to account-page to change password.